# function to get number of columns in a NumPy array that returns 1 if it is a 1D array

Tags: python, numpy, shapes

I have defined operations on `3xN` `NumPy` arrays, and I want to loop over each column of the array.

I tried:

```
for i in range(nparray.shape[1]):
```

However, if `nparray.ndim == 1`, this fails.

Is there a clean way to ascertain the number of columns of a `NumPy` array, for example, to get `1` if it is a `1D` array (like MATLAB's `size` operation does)?

Otherwise, I have implemented:

```
if nparray.ndim == 1:
    num_points = 1
else:
    num_points = nparray.shape[1]

for i in range(num_points):
```

Comment: As a side note, why are you looping over the column indices instead of just looping over the columns in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just looking for something less verbose, you could do this:

```
num_points = np.atleast_2d(nparray).shape[1]
```

That will, of course, make a new temporary array just to take its shape, which is a little silly… but it'll be pretty cheap, because it's just a view of the same memory.

However, I think your explicit code is more readable, except that I might do it with a `try`:

```
try:
    num_points = nparray.shape[1]
except IndexError:
    num_points = 1
```

If you're doing this repeatedly, whatever you do, you should wrap it in a function. For example:

```
def num_points(arr, axis):
    try:
        return arr.shape[axis]
    except IndexError:
        return 1
```

Then all you have to write is:

```
for i in range(num_points(nparray, 1)):
```

And of course it means you can change things everywhere by just editing one place, e.g.,:

```
def num_points(arr, axis):
    return nparray[:,...,np.newaxis].shape[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep the one-liner, how about using [conditional expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/):

```
for i in range(nparray.shape[1] if nparray.ndim > 1 else 1):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, to iterate a `np.array` means to iterate over the rows. If you have to iterate over columns, just iterate through the transposed array:

```
>>> a2=array(range(12)).reshape((3,4))
>>> for col in a2.T:
    print col

[0 4 8]
[1 5 9]
[ 2  6 10]
[ 3  7 11]
```

What's the intended behavior of an array `array([1,2,3])`, it is treated as having one column or having 3 cols? It is confusing that you mentioned that the arrays are all 3XN arrays, which means this should be the intended behavior, as it should be treated as having just 1 column:

```
>>> a1=array(range(3))
>>> for col in a1.reshape((3,-1)).T:
print col

[0 1 2]
```

So, a general solution: `for col in your_array.reshape((3,-1)).T: #do something`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use the `len` function:

```
for i in range(len(nparray)):
   ...
```

Why? Because if the number of nparray is a like a one dimensional vector, `len` will return the number of elements. In your case, the number of columns.

```
nparray = numpy.ones(10)
print(len(nparray))
Out: 10
```

If nparray is like a matrix, the number of columns will be returned.

```
nparray = numpy.ones((10, 5))
print(len(nparray))
Out: 10
```

If you have a list of numpy arrays with different sizes, just use `len` inside a loop based on your list.